# How to align text with ons-select?

Tags: html, onsen-ui

I have this HTML snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Label for select:&nbsp;
        <ons-select id="any_id" modifier="material">
            <option value="0">Value 0</option>
            <option value="1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        </ons-select>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Which produces this:

[image: Text is not properly aligned with ons-select. How to fix this?]

As you can see, the text is not properly aligned with `ons-select`. How can I make them display on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flexbox for this type of thing.  Very easy to implement.

```css
div{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      Label for select:&nbsp;   
     
        <ons-select id="any_id" modifier="material">
            <option value="0">Value 0</option>
            <option value="1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        </ons-select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just gonna add : you can add `justify-content: center;` to the css class to center it all.